# How can the electron framework enable communication like an Ajax request?

Tags: electron

`ipcRenderer.sendSync` may block the whole renderer process. `ipcRenderer.send` need use `ipcRenderer.on` to listen for the asynchronous return of events.

So is there a way of communicating that data can be returned as a callback directly where it was requested?

It might look something like this: `ipcRenderer.sendAsync('eventName', args, callback)`, Or by other means.

```js
ipcRenderer.on("onMessage", (e, {cbName, data}) => { 
  switch (cbName) {
    case 'foo1':
      foo1(data)
      break
    case 'foo2':
      foo2(data)
      break
    case 'foo3':
      foo2(data)
      break
    // more
    default:
      break
  }
})

ipcRenderer.send("message", { cbName, /* other args */ })
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. Are you saying that you want to send a message from the renderer to the main process and have the main process call a callback with the result instead of sending it back?

Comment: @pushkin Oh, that's just what I want!

Comment: And that callback needs to live in the renderer process I'm guessing? Or can it be in main

Comment: So you just want to send the callback name from the main process to renderer and execute the callback in the renderer? What is stopping you from doing that? You can just send data back with `e.sender.send("onMessage", cbname, otherData);` like you normally would. what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

what you need is ipcMain.handle() and ipcRenderer.invoke()
this will return a promise back to renderer.

```
// Main process
ipcMain.handle('my-invokable-ipc', async (event, ...args) => {
  const result = await somePromise(...args)
  return result
})

// Renderer process
async () => {
  const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('my-invokable-ipc', arg1, arg2)
  // ...
}
```

For further info
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for, if I understand it correctly, is to pass a callback from the renderer process to the main process and have the handler in main call into it with the response rather than sending it back.

so rather than doing this:

main.js:

```
ipcMain.on("message", (e, arg) => {
    e.sender.send("onMessage", "response");
});
```

renderer.js:

```
ipcRenderer.send("message", 1);
ipcRenderer.on("onMessage", (e, response) => { });
```

you want to do this:

main.js:

```
ipcMain.on("message", (e, arg, callback) => {
    callback("response");
});
```

renderer.js:

```
function callback(response) { }
ipcRenderer.send("message", 1, callback);
```

Then no, you can't do that because you can't pass functions across processes like this. Even if you `.toString()` the function and then recreate the function in the main process via `new Function(...)`, you would be executing it in the context of the main process, not the renderer, and presumably you'd want to execute it in the renderer process.

Using `e.sender.send(...)` is the idiomatic way of sending messages back to the other process, and you shouldn't shy away from it.

Comment: Now, I need to use the same `ipcRenderer.send` to fetch data from the main process in different parts of the rendering process, and then do something different. Too bad if you need to make an id in the parameters you send and then judge the parameters in `ipRender.on` to execute different functions.

Comment: can you can update your question with a specific example, so I can better understand your needs? I don't understand your comment

Comment: Updated the problem